# Xamarin.Forms app on iOS has 2 Navigation Bars instead of 1

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and using Navigation Pages. When I run on the Android, there is a single navigation bar visible that updates for each page. When I run on iOS, there is always a navigation bar at the very top that takes me to the root page, and then all subsequent pages use a second navigation bar beneath that. Is this expected behavior on an iOS app? I would rather have one navigation bar instead of 2, how can I achieve this?

I'm running on iPhone SE iOS 10.0 using latest alpha version of Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a `NavigationPage` inside of a `NavigationPage`. From a navigation perspective, it's a rather bad idea.

If you have to nest high-level pages, it usually goes like this:

`[MasterDetailPage] > [TabbedPage] > [NavigationPage] > ContentPage`

It means: only use a `MasterDetailPage` as your `App.MainPage`, and do not put `TabbedPage` in `NavigationPage` but prefer the other way around.

This is what will give you the best experience for the user, and consistent results in `Xamarin.Forms`

Note that `Tab>MDP>` works as well, but makes less sense from an user story perspective.

Comment: Thank you, that's good info. I'm new to Xamarin and even new to mobile and coming from Windows development. My MainPage is a navigation page and after successful login I use Navigation.PushAsync to go to the Home Screen. Are you saying I should make the Login page a MasterDetailPage, then follow the same process to navigate? I'll pay around with it and see how it behaves.

Comment: can you share any sample code so we can see what is going on?